# how to convert query with multiple group by columns to CActiveDataProvider in Yii 1.1.14?

Tags: yii

I need to conver this sql statement that has a multi column group by clause into CActiveDataProvider in Yii version 1.1.4?

```
select * from my_table_name  group by  bookname,categorytitle,bookkey order by bookname,categorytitle,bookkey asc;
```

I need a CActiveDataProvider to feed a CGridView search function. Apparently, I only have a simple return in my model of the search function that runs my CGridView

```
    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this),
        array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => array(
                'defaultOrder' => 'id ASC'
            ),
            'pagination' => array('pageSize' => ActiveRecord::PAGE_SIZE),
        ));
```

so how to convert the sql statement that I gave into CActiveDataProvider format ?

Comment: make sql view and than create yii model and use this in your controller or page view. another solution create custom search function in your existing model and use group by e.g. - `$criteria->group = "bookname,categorytitle,bookkey"; $criteria->order = "bookname,categorytitle,bookkey";`

Comment: you  should  have put  your answer in the box at the bottom so that I can select it as answer. thanks..please transfer it ..lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using two way -

- Make sql view and than create yii model and use this in your
  controller or page view.
- Create custom search function in your existing model and use group by

e.g. -

```
<?php
public function new_search(){
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

  ...
  ..

  $criteria->group = "bookname, categorytitle, bookkey"; 
  $criteria->order = "bookname, categorytitle, bookkey";

  return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>100)
  ));
}
?>
```